# Vscode C/C++ debugger console implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug my C++ program using vscode. I am rather familiar with codeblocks but want to be able to to same with vscode. I have installed all the extensions needed including intellisense but after launching a debug session I keep on getting the message:
**Unable to start debugging. Not implemented.** What am I getting wrong? Below is my launch.json file

```
{
   
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:/Users/USER/Documents/Works/Codex/C++ Files/Vector/main.cpp",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `"program"` needs to be the `exe` file, not your C/C++ entry file (`main.cpp`)